# Azure Data Factory fails to create Azure SQL linked service utilising Managed private endpoint

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have  created and approved a managed private endpoint in Azure Data Factory, targeting my Azure SQL server (which has public network access disabled).

I have also created a database user for the System Assigned Managed Identity.

When attempting to add a new linked service in the Data Factory portal, I am able to select my Azure subscription and the Server name, as shown in the screenshot below.  However, the Database name dropdown never moves beyond "Loading..."

[image: New linked service dialog, showing "Database name: Loading..."]

Attempting to create the linked service via Bicep instead seems to succeed - but reviewing the linked services blade, the linked service is not "Using private endpoint" - and my data pipeline fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix: Ensure SQL server name is all lowercase.**

Checking my browser console whilst the above screen was displayed, I noticed an error relating to validation of the Server name, specifically "Servername cannot be empty or null. It can only be made up of lowercase letters, the numbers 0-9 and the hyphen. The hyphen may not lead or trail in the name."

My server name contained capital letters (although the Data Factory UI was rendering it in all lower case).

After recreating my Azure SQL server, with a name complying with the requirements above, I was able to set up the linked service without issue (both through the UI and through Bicep).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try with enabling interactive authoting option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private

Comment: Interactive authoring